# Работа с двумя контроллерами (Spring MVC + Security)

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

У меня есть два контроллера, я хочу чтобы сначала запустился
"AuthorizationController"

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class  AuthorizationController{

    // If user will be successfully authenticated he/she will be taken to the login secure page.
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
        m.addObject("title", "Вы успешно вошли");
        m.addObject("message", "Основная");
        m.setViewName("admin");

        return m;
    }

    // Spring security will see this message.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, 
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        m.addObject("error", "Неверный логин и пароль");        
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        m.addObject("msg", "Вы успешно вышли");     
    }

    m.setViewName("login");
     redirAttrbs.addFlashAttribute("ключ", "параметр");
             return new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");
}
```

}

```
    }
}
```

После того как админ зайдет с помощью логина и пароля он должен переместится в "StudentController" и показал всех студентов как можно реализовать
StudentController

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вы хотите сделать редирект после успешной авторизации. Это делается так:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginValidate(RedirectAttributes redirAttrbs){
    // прочий код
    redirAttrbs.addFlashAttribute("ключ", "параметр");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/контекст/куда/перенаправлять");
}
```

В объект `RedirectAttributes` пишем аттрибуты, которые хотим передать в другой контроллер (если имеется).

Кстати, такого рода метод должен быть POST.

Comment: Можете написать полностью код пожалуйста, я пробывал но ошибка заново на месте все вернул ибо боюсь что сломаю программу

Comment: Вероятно вы используете Spring Security. Вам следует почитать подробнее про настройку этого фреймворка. Если у вас Spring Boot, то хотя бы тут: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration

Comment: у меня Spring Framework. Посмотрите вопрос сейчас я правлю может я что то не так написал